# Automatically remove the cancelled meetings

Tags: vba, outlook

Whenever I receive meeting cancellation, I would like to remove the meeting cancellation request from my inbox **and** remove the meeting from the Calendar. Below code works for removing the email, but does not remove the meeting. I have to manually go to calendar and click on "Remove from Calendar". Any ideas?

```
Sub RemoveCancelledMeetingEmails()
    Dim objInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objInboxItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim i As Long


    Set objInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    For Each Item In objInbox.Items
        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MeetingItem Then
            Dim objMeeting As Outlook.MeetingItem: Set objMeeting = Item
            If objMeeting.Class = 54 Then
                Dim objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
                'Set objAppointment = objMeeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
                'objMeeting.Display
                objMeeting.Delete
                'Item.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Uncommment the `GetAssociatedAppointment` line (change the parameter to false to avoid creating an appointment if it does not exist) and call `objAppointment.Delete`

Comment: If the meeting is cancelled, calling the GetAssociatedAppointment returns Nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure. But MeetingItem.Class property will be 54 (OlObjectClass.olMeetingCancellation)

Comment: I think I am missing something. When a cancelled meeting email comes, the calendar shows up as Cancelled, but doesn't remove the meeting. Running the above code only removes the email and not the appointment. It still shows in calendar as Cancelled and I have to manually open the invite and click on remove from calendar.  Do you have any other way to make both removed?

Comment: Doesn't GetAssociatedAppointment(false) return the existing (cancelled) appointment?

Comment: I tried using GetAssociatedAppointment(false) and it doesn't return cancelled appointments

Comment: I can only suggest searching for the appointment explicitly (MAPIFolder.Items.Find) or using Redemption (its version of RDOMeetingItems.GetAssociatedAppointment does not have any limitations

Answer (score 0):

```
Set olResCalendar = OpenMAPIFolder("\MailboxName\Calendar")
Sub RemoveCanceledAppointments()
Dim olResCalendar As Outlook.MAPIFolder, olApptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem, 
intCounter As Integer
'Change the path to the resource calendar on the next line
Set olResCalendar = OpenMAPIFolder("\MailboxName\Calendar")
For intCounter = olResCalendar.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
Set olApptItem = olResCalendar.Items(intCounter)
    If Left(olApptItem.Subject, 9) = "Canceled:" Then
    olApptItem.Delete
    End If
Next
Set olApptItem = Nothing
Set olResCalendar = Nothing
End Sub
Function OpenMAPIFolder(szPath)
Dim app, ns, flr, szDir, i
Set flr = Nothing
Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    If Left(szPath, Len("\")) = "\" Then
    szPath = Mid(szPath, Len("\") + 1)
    Else
    Set flr = app.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    End If
While szPath <> ""
i = InStr(szPath, "\")
    If i Then
    szDir = Left(szPath, i - 1)
    szPath = Mid(szPath, i + Len("\"))
    Else
    szDir = szPath
    szPath = ""
    End If
    If IsNothing(flr) Then
    Set ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set flr = ns.Folders(szDir)
    Else
    Set flr = flr.Folders(szDir)
    End If
    Wend
Set OpenMAPIFolder = flr
End Function
Function IsNothing(Obj)
If TypeName(Obj) = "Nothing" Then
    IsNothing = True
Else
    IsNothing = False
End If
End Function
```

From: https://superuser.com/questions/663992/how-can-i-set-outlook-2010-to-automatically-remove-cancelled-meeting

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the code that works now.

```
Sub deleteFromInbox()
Dim oMeetingItem As Outlook.MeetingItem
Dim oAppointmentItem As AppointmentItem
Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set oItems = oInbox.Items.Restrict("[MessageClass] = 'IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Canceled'")
For Each oAppt In oItems
    If TypeOf oAppt Is MeetingItem Then
        Set oMeetingItem = oAppt
        If Len(oAppt.Subject) > 0 And InStr(1, oAppt.Subject, "Canceled:") <> 0 Then
            Set oAppointmentItem = oMeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(False)
            Debug.Print oAppt.Subject
            If Not oAppointmentItem Is Nothing Then
                oAppointmentItem.Delete
            End If
           oAppt.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```

End Sub